# MongoDB replication factors

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'm new to Mongo, have been using Cassandra for a while.  I didn't find any clear answers from Mongo's docs.  My questions below are all closely related.

1) How to specify the replication factors in Mongo?

In C* you can define replication factors (how many replicas) for the entire database and/or for each table.  Mongo's newer replica set concept is similar to C*'s idea.  But, I don't see how I can define the replication factors for each table/collection in Mongo.  Where to define that in Mongo?

2) Replica sets and replication factors?

It seems you can define multiple replica sets in a Mongo cluster for your databases.  A replica set can have up to 7 voting members.  Does a 5-member replica set means the data is replicated 5 times?  Or replica sets are only for voting the primary?

3) Replica sets for what collections?

The replica set configuration doc didn't mention anything about databases or collections.  Is there a way to specify what collections a replica set is intended for?

4) Replica sets definition?

If I wanted to create a 15-node Mongo cluster and keeping 3 copies of each record, how to partition the nodes into multiple replica sets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Mongo replication works by replicating the entire ***instance***. It is not done at the individual database or collection level. All replicas contain a copy of the data except for arbiters. Arbiters do not hold any data and only participate in elections of a new primary. They are usually deployed to create enough of a majority that if an instance goes down a new instance can be elected as the primary.

Its pretty well explained here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

Comment: So for my 15-node and 3-replica case, I actually only needs 3 nodes, the other 12 nodes cannot be used effectively unless I shard the collections?

Comment: Depending on your needs you could place all 15 in a replica set and use secondary reads in order to take the burden off your primary as long as your'e ok with potentially stale data. Otherwise yes you could shard but my experience with sharding is limited and its a complex endeavor. You should only shard when you know you absolutely have to, not because you just have extra machines laying around.

Comment: Hmm, looks to me Mongo still hasn't solved the scalability issue.  If I know keeping 3 replicas are enough, and by having additional machines, Mongo should automatically creates multiple virtual replica sets (3 members in each set in my case) to evenly and automatically distribute all the data and get managed by those replica sets, and that'll scale up like Cassandra does.  The current replica set thing can't help to scale up without manual sharding, in a sense, it's still an entire database instance on a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

Replication is referred to the process of ensuring that the same data is available on more than one Mongo DB Server. This is sometimes required for the purpose of increasing data availability.

Because if your main MongoDB Server goes down for any reason, there will be no access to the data. But if you had the data replicated to another server at regular intervals, you will be able to access the data from another server even if the primary server fails.

Another purpose of replication is the possibility of load balancing. If there are many users connecting to the system, instead of having everyone connect to one system, users can be connected to multiple servers so that there is an equal distribution of the load.

In MongoDB, multiple MongDB Servers are grouped in sets called Replica sets. The Replica set will have a primary server which will accept all the write operation from clients. All other instances added to the set after this will be called the secondary instances which can be used primarily for all read operations.